# Equivalent isFirstRender hook for StrictMode in development mode

Tags: reactjs

Previously I've used a hook like this to determine if a component is being rendered for the first time:

```
function useIsFirstRender() {
  const isFirst = useRef(true);

  if (isFirst.current) {
    isFirst.current = false;

    return true;
  }

  return isFirst.current;
}

function App() {
  const isFirstRender = useIsFirstRender();

  useEffect(() => {
    if (isFirstRender) {
      // It's the first render
    }
  }, []); // I'd expect [] to cause useEffect's first param to be called once, but with StrictMode this doesn't happen.
}
```

Since starting to use StrictMode in React 18, this hook no longer functions as I expect, as my component is being rendered twice due to how StrictMode works in development, and `isFirstRender` is `true` on both renders. Instead I'm having to implement `useRef` directly in each of my components as per https://github.com/reactwg/react-18/discussions/18

```
function App() {
  const isFirstRender = useRef(true);

  useEffect(() => {
    if (isFirstRender.current === true) {
      isFirstRender.current = false;

      // It's the first render
    }
  }, []);
}
```

I'm looking to make another re-usable hook so that I don't need to reimplement the `useRef` logic in every component where I need this behaviour.

I'm aware that this double rendering behaviour only happens in development mode. However some of the actions that I want to take only on the first render involve calling an API that isn't idempotent, so during development this is making things very difficult.

Answer (score 4):

What about this kind of `useFirstRender` hook? This can be reused in every component, its callback called only at the first render. After unmount it also called again once at remount.

Update 1:
<strike>For clarification, this actually run on second render, because I think the first render added by strict mode is not what you are interested in, but obviously it can be modified to run on the first render of react 18 strict mode and ignore the second one. I don't know which one makes more sense for you.</strike>

Update 2: I don't know why I thought it is good idea to run on second run honestly, as the additional run is the second one, based on reactwg discussion.I changed it to run on actual first render, and not more:) If unmounted then remounted it again triggers the callback only *once*.

```
function useFirstRender(callback) {
  const isFirst = useRef(false);

  if (!isFirst.current) {
    isFirst.current = true;
  }

  useEffect(() => {
    if (isFirst.current) {
      callback();
    }
    return () => {
      isFirst.current = false;
    };
  }, []);
}

function Component() {
    useFirstRender(() => {
        console.log('Rendered first time');
    });
    return <div>Component</div>;
}

function App() {
    return (
        <React.StrictMode>
            <Component/>
        </React.StrictMode>
    );
}
```

Answer (score 1):

This sounds to be a strange question since passing an empty array as second argument of `useEffect` has exactly the effect you are asking for, requiring nothing more.

Could it be that the problem is not the code runs twice, but your component is unmounted and mounted once again?

I suggest you to add following code to your component just to detect if that's the case:

```
function App() {
  // Add this
  let counterA = 0;
  let counterB = 0;
  useEffect(() => {
    console.log("counterA", counterA++);

    return () => console.log("counterB", counterB++);
  }, []);

  // Follows the rest of your code
}
```

In my console I can see only `counterA 0` and later `counterB 0` when the component is unmounted.

If you see `counterA 1`, `counterA 2`, etc... the problem is outside of my knowledge and you can ignore this answer; but if you can see `counterA 0` and `counterB 0` multiple times, **React.js** works as intended and probably you have to rethink about the way you control how and when your API is called; Context may help you.

The reason why **React.js** in StrictMode **and** in development environment runs some code twice (as `setState` function) is exactly to help us detecting bad implementations. Seeking for way to avoid this barrier right with the purpose to be free to do bad implementations sounds as a very bad idea. ;)

**Edit:** I updated the App I used to test this to the latest versions and latest best practices and (only in development environment) I see `counterA 0`, `counterB 0` and `counterA 1` in rapid sequence: it's time to refactor some of my code too!

Comment: > Could it be that the problem is not the code runs twice, but your component is unmounted and mounted once again?  

Well, this is exactly what StrictMode does in React 18 when you're in development mode, it deliberately mounts and unmounts and remounts your components.  

What I'm searching for is a reusable way to use a `useRef` such that a component that mounts->unmounts->mounts only runs a section of code on the first mount.

Comment: Yes @DaveIrvine , while studying about your question I learned that. The only point we need to clarify is that React.js does not mount and unmount and remount component deliberately, it does that exactly with the purpose to help us detecting bad implementations (React.js hook handlers should be idempotent). That's why it's better to refactor our code when we discover we did bad things rather than seeking for an hack to deliberately let us doing bad things.

Comment: I agree, but what I'm trying to achieve I don't think falls into "bad implementations". I want to achieve what is discussed here: https://github.com/reactwg/react-18/discussions/18 under "Effects that should only run once can use a ref.". I want my effect to run once, so I want to use a ref, but what I want to do is abstract this pattern away so that updating the ref doesn't need to be handled in each of my components.

Comment: We could discuss about what does fall or doesn't into "bad implementations" for years probably generating nothing more than a religious war :) that's why I'll not start that discussion. What I can say is that reading the article in you last comment it seems that in the opinion of React maintainers what you're trying to achieve does. `So the first instinct that "I want this to run once!" is often wrong.` **gaearon** on May 28, 2021 _Maintainer_